# How can I reliably parse and store data using reliable asynchronous messages?

Tags: wcf, jms, msmq, messaging, apache-camel

I'm developing a system that receives messages related to patient activity in a hospital, parses and stores this data (HL7 2.x messages). 
Some messages may contain basic patient information, other messages could contain lab results, transcribed documents, etc.

I'd like to use an asynchronous reliable messaging system to do this (such as WCF + MSMQ or Apache Camel + ActiveMQ. It seems like these technologies would be a good fit.

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply these technologies to solve the problem though.
If a message comes in and something goes wrong when parsing and storing data for a patient I need to halt processing of incoming messages for this patient until the problem is resolved.

I don't really want to stop processing messages for all patients if a problem occurs, just messages for the single patient that has a problem.

Is there a design pattern or some method of handling situations like this that I'm missing?

I'll most likely use a database to store the messages and keep track of individual patient queues. If an error occurs I can lock the patient so messages will no longer be processed until the problem is resolved.

I'm just looking for a sanity check. Is there an easier way to do this, or is manually  managing queues and patients in the database a reasonable way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very similar to a recent requirement from a client, here is how we solved this in Camel/ActiveMQ...

- used ActiveMQ [message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) to single-thread processing (preserve order, etc) for a given patient and still allow multi-threaded processing
- setup Camel [exception handling](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) to add patients to an exception list (stored in [Hazelcast](http://camel.apache.org/hazelcast-component.html) or [Cache](http://camel.apache.org/cache.html)) when processing errors occur
- used a Camel [filter](http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html) to route messages for exception list patients to an exception queue
- setup a timer to periodically retry messages from the exception queue
- setup email notifications when exceptions occurred (use an [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) if this is high volume to group messages into fewer emails, etc.)
- used [ActiveMQ JMX](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html) to manually view/retry/move/delete messages to triage them appropriately (built a web based console to support this)

Answer (score 1):

You could possible use a Content Based Router
http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

And then route messages for "trouble patients" to a special queue. And for patients with no problems you can process them as usual.

Then when a patient is "fixed" you can use a JMS selector to pickup the messages for that patient from the "trouble queue" and put back on the regular queue, so they are re-processed.

Answer (score 0):

How to handle failures for a particular patient ID.

Well having a message queue per patient does not scale at all. You could have 1000's of patients so you would need to maintain the same number of queues. Nightmare.

So to handle multiple patient records on the same queue you need to make the service which reads from you queue fault-tolerant.

What I mean is that if the service cannot process a de-queued message (maybe due to data issues with the message, or downstream dependencies being unavailable) then the service can do one or more of the following:

1. Retry a configured number of times (with a configured frequency)
2. Route that message, along with any error/diagnostics information, to another message queue or another process.
3. Do nothing and allow the time-to-live time-out on the message to expire so it is handled as a bad message by the queueing system (not recommended).

If you have a requirement that messages for a single patient always be processed in order then you have a different challenge and need to implement a go/no-go lookup for each message before allowing it to be processed. This is a standard ordered-delivery implementation.

Hope this helps.

I think maybe you should re-post a new question or multiple questions with a more focused challenge you are facing. I get the feeling you are facing multiple challenges at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

http://ignaciosuay.com/unit-testing-hl7-messages-with-apache-camel/I will suggest you to use activemq and camel with the redelivery option on. So if something goes wrong you the message will be redeliver until the message will be processed. Also, You can specify the number of times that could be redeliver. Please, have a look at the camel redilvery policy:

http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html

Also, I have written an easy test example which use camel and hl7, that maybe will help you:

http://ignaciosuay.com/unit-testing-hl7-messages-with-apache-camel/